# How can you create a feedback diagram where the loops have rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams, technical-drawing

[image]

I am currently using MS paint to draw diagrams such as these. However, I would like the loops at the top and at the bottom (line with arrows connecting the blocks) to have rounded corners, as opposed to sharp corners. (More like $\subset$ rather than $\sqsubset$)

Is there a way to do this either in Tikz or some other tool that generates high fidelity diagrams?

This question has been bothering me forever!

Comment: Yes, just add `rounded corners=<radius>` to the path and TikZ does the rest for you. For those kind of arrows, see [Q102385](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385).

Comment: Try adapting [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272999/106162)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation of @Ignasy answer, but with some (off-topic) image and image code improvements/changes. Differences are marked in code by `<---`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,        % <--- added
                ext.paths.ortho,    % <--- added
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {-Latex, rounded corners=4mm},
lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=red, auto},
  N/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm}
                        ]           % <--- added image elements styles
\node[N] (a) {$\displaystyle \int \cos x \,dx$};    % <--- changed
\node[N, right=of a] (b) {$x^2 \sin x$};            % <--- changed

\draw[arr]  (a)  r-ud [distance=-10mm] node[lbl]  {$a$ to $b$} (b);    % <--- changed
\draw[arr]  (b)  r-du [distance=-10mm] node[lbl]  {$b$ to $a$} (a);    % <--- changed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Now is considered @Qrrbrbirlbel, the *TikZ-Extensions* package author, comment.

Comment: `\footnotesize` needs to be an argument of `/utils/exec`, `font` or `node font`. For this, the udlr paths can be used without having to use the explicit anchor: `\draw[arr]  (a) r-ud [ud distance=10mm] node[lbl] {$a$ to $b$} (b); \draw[arr]  (b) r-du [du distance=10mm] node[lbl] {$a$ to $b$} (a);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you very much for your comment. Regarding to drawing of arrows, I just miss this possibility in package documentation. Regarding font size for edge labels, now I see that my test file actually for font size has `font=\footnotesize`. Both are now corrected.

Comment: This is very beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw] (a) {$\int \cos x \,dx$};
        \node[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw, right=2cm of a] (b) {$x^2 \sin x$};
        \draw[-latex, rounded corners] (a) --++(90:2cm)-| node[near start, red, above]{$a$ to $b$} (b);
        \draw[-latex, rounded corners] (b) --++(-90:2cm) -| node[near start, red, below]{$b$ to $a$} (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good: +1..

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] 
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (.8,.5) node[midway] (a) {$\int \cos x \,dx$};
        \draw (2,0) rectangle (2.8,.5) node[midway] (b) {$x^2 \sin x$};
        \draw[-latex] (.4,.5) to [out=60,in=120] node[red, above]{$a$ to $b$} (2.4,.5);
        \draw[-latex] (2.4,0) to [out=-120,in=-60] node[red, below]{$b$ to $a$} (.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: better look with '[out=90,in=90]' (upper ronded arrow) and '[out=-90,in=-90]' (lower rounded arrow).